# Installing zfs on Docker Ubuntu jammy image

Tags: docker, ubuntu-22.04, zfs

I am running into a problem with getting zfs running on a Ubuntu jammy (22.04 LTS) Docker image.

If I start with a fresh image and run

```
apt update
apt install zfsutils-linux -y
zpool create ....
```

I get the following error:

> The ZFS modules are not loaded. Try running '/sbin/modprobe zfs' as root to load them.

After installing modprobe and attempting the command gives the following error:

> modprobe: FATAL: Module zfs not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-1027-gcp

Does anyone know what I need to do to get zfs working on this image?

I have already tried:

- apt install zfs-dkms
- Building the latest zfs from source

Comment: Docker containers run on top of, and share, the host's kernel. I think you need to install ZFS on the host and not in a container.

Comment: ...and you can't manipulate raw filesystems at this level inside a container; its filesystem is heavily managed by the Docker daemon itself.  A virtual machine could be an option here too.

Comment: @HansKilian Thanks. Installing zfs on the host machine worked.

Comment: @DavidMaze I was kind of afraid that would be the case. After trying to create a zpool it gave me an error of unable to label the disk. I assume it's because zfs cannot be run like this inside a Docker container.

Comment: Have you tried using the ``--privileged`` flag when running the container?